# Realex payment gateway after successfully payment not return Merchant website

Tags: payment-gateway, oscommerce, realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

Using realex payment i'm try to checkout order with Oscommerce code, Payment deducted from bank and also trasection display in realex system but user can not get back Merchant website and order status is not updated due to return url or other may be from realex.
[image]

Please check screenshot, this issue is sometime happen and sometime working well.
Pardon if any grammar mistake

Answer (score 1):

This message indicates that the Global Payments HPP was unable to connect to the OSCommerce response page or your server (511 error code). Common causes of this issue can be server firewall rules or that the response page isn't functioning correctly.

The Global Payments support team will be able to provide you with more information if you provide them with an Order ID you used where this issue occurred. You can also check your server logs at the the moment the HPP should have connected to it and look for any errors reported.